# Unable to setup scaffold due to missing method

Tags: grails

I am trying to setup scaffold to get a visual rep for my database testing. I am able to see the controller option on the webpage but upon clicking it, I get the following error.

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException
>
> No signature of method: static
> grails.artefact.DomainClass.count() is applicable for argument types:
> () values: [] Possible solutions: print(java.io.PrintWriter),
> print(java.lang.Object), wait(), any(), dump(), collect()

Not able to understand what is going on. Trying to look at docs and nothing seems to point to this. I am just having a Class and setting up a controller for that class as follows. Unsure what I am doing wrong. Doubt its relevant but the class names for Award and OnlineOrder are correct.

**Controller**

```
package rewards

import grails.artefact.DomainClass

class CustomerController {

    static scaffold = DomainClass

    //def index() {}
}
```

Class

```
package rewards

class Customer {

    String firstName
    String lastName
    long phone
    String email
    int totalPoints

    static hasMany = [awards:Award, orders:OnlineOrder]

    static constraints = {

    }
}
```

Comment: Try using `static scaffold = true` or `static scaffold = Customer` instead of `static scaffold = DomainClass`.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore I was trying with = true which was throwing errors and tried with DomainClass. Changing it to = Customer does resolve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
package rewards

import grails.artefact.DomainClass

class CustomerController {

    static scaffold = DomainClass

}
```

`grails.artefact.DomainClass` is a trait.  You can't scaffold a trait.  The value that you assign to the `scaffold` property needs to be your domain class.  For example...

```
package rewards

class CustomerController {

    static scaffold = Person

}
```

Comment: I am using static scaffold = Customer now and it is working. My understanding was that DomainClass will be substituted with the name of the controller automatically, in this case Customer. Guess I was wrong.

Comment: "My understanding was that DomainClass will be substituted with the name of the controller automatically, in this case Customer." - That is not the case.